# Finding occurences of string in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column in Excel filled with non uniform data and I need to find the occurrences of strings within it.

Example table:

http://is.gd/RGvXND

Using =COUNTIF(A:A, "*"&B2&"*") would work, with the exception of "Apple", which appears twice in the same cell.

How do you overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How many duplicates can you have? Use the following formula, updating the row 10 to your maximum number of duplicates. Enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as this is an array formula.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,REPT("*"&$B2&*",ROW($1:$10))))
```

Comment: While it does appear to work in small scale, turning this formula to array breaks Excel. I should mention column A has 600-1000k rows, some are a bit long. It would eventually be static data, I just try to avoid using a 3rd party software to do all the calculations.

Comment: How many rows / potential duplicates do you have? The array formula can be taxing on system resources, in which case a user-defined function might be better advised.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another formula option, but again it might be slow with a large amount of data

`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A$2:A$10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$2:A$10,B2,"")))/LEN(B2)`